# Disallow specific words in JIRA issue description

Tags: jira, jira-agile

There's a product manager that tends throw words like "probably" and "maybe" into his requirements. Is there a way in JIRA administration to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People problem - solve by discussing it with the person

Answer (score 0):

Give [Suite Utilities for JIRA](https://jsutil.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JSUTIL/JIRA+Suite+Utilities+Workflow+Validators) a try: prohibit changing of description during issue editing and let it change via transition. On this transition you can put regex validator which would let you filter not desirable phrases.